# How to access an array from another class?

Tags: c++

Im trying to access my array y from that is passwordgame class, I declared the array in public in passwordgame class in order to make it accessible in my other class.

This is what i used to have when y whats global variable.

```
for (int j =0; j < 4; j ++ ) {
                bool flag = false;

                if ( x[j] ==  y[j] ) {
                    cout << "O";
                    finish[j] = true;
                    continue;

                }
```

now as y variable inside the class PasswordGame I do this, and my error is "  member reference base type "int" is not a structure or union".

```
PasswordGuessingGame u;
     for (int j =0; j < 4; j ++ ) {
                    bool flag = false;

                    if ( x[j] ==  u.y[j] ) {
                        cout << "O";
                        finish[j] = true;
                        continue;

                    }
```

However if I declare in public, it would work but then in the loop is not working properly.

```
public: 
int two = u.y[j];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show your definition of `PasswordGuessingGame` class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you declare your class definition.But just to demonstration here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

class PasswordGuessingGame{
public :
int x[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
};

class anotherClass{
public :
int y[5]={11,22,33,4,6};

};
int main(){
PasswordGuessingGame u;
anotherClass v;

int finish[5];
for (int j =0; j < 4; j ++ ) {
            bool flag = false;

            if ( u.x[j] ==  v.y[j] ) {
                std::cout << "O";
                finish[j] = true;
            }
        }
return 0;
}
```